# Hyperledger Fabric- How do I resolve 'ProposalResponsePayloads do not match' when my smart contract is deterministic?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to invoke a chaincode function that sets details about a crop.
This function doesn't use date/time, and is logically deterministic. I've checked that the chaincode is successfully installed for each organization of the channel and committed to the channel using `peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled` and `peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted`.

However, when I run `peer chaincode invoke`, it yields an error `Error: could not assemble transaction: ProposalResponsePayloads do not match`.

There was a broader question that covered some common causes of error, but I'm not completely sure if any of the reasons listed are applicable in my case ([Hyperledger Fabric: Error: could not assemble transaction: ProposalResponsePayloads do not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289283/hyperledger-fabric-error-could-not-assemble-transaction-proposalresponsepaylo)).

This was the invoke command:

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n papercontract --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:11051 --tlsRootCertFiles /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:12051 --tlsRootCertFiles /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/peers/peer0.org4.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:13051 --tlsRootCertFiles /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org5.example.com/peers/peer0.org5.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"function":"plant","Args":["bhut jolokia", "ghost pepper farms", "sustainable agriculture company", "two dozen", "three quintal per year", "yes", "polyculture", "organic, pesticide-free", "direct sowing"]}'
```

Here is what the error message looks like, after adding some newlines and tabs:

```
Error: could not assemble transaction:
ProposalResponsePayloads do not match -
proposal response: version:1 response:<status:200

payload:"{
    \"field1\":\"\",
    \"field2\":\"\",
    \"field3\":\"\",
    \"field4\":\"\",
    \"field5\":\"\"}" >
    
payload:"\n \335-\3101\315<\016\327\324\005\037\202%\360\305\177\2369T\273\334\324X\363\020\302\"f\r6\030\373\022\325\020\n\343\010\022>\n\n_lifecycle\0220\n.\n(namespaces/fields/papercontract/Sequence\022\002\010\016\022\240\010\n\rpapercontract\022\216\010\032\213\010\n\030\000SpiceList\000bhut jolokia\000\032\356\007{
    \"field1\":\"\",
    \"field2\":\"\",
    \"field4\":\"\",
    \"splitKey\":[\"bhut jolokia\"],
    \"field3\":\"\",
    \"field5\":\"\"}"}
    
\032\330\007\010\310\001\032\322\007{
    \"field1\":\"\",
    \"field3\":\"\",
    \"field4\":\"\",
    \"field2\":\"\",
    \"field5\":\"\"}"}
    
\"\022\022\rpapercontract\032\0010" endorsement:<endorser:"\n\007Org4MSP\022\252\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nDn2uHMeio475cLoKbayZo87BRDsykM1rBNl1/bI=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" signature:"0D\002 \013v\273\205\327I >1\212\007\031\233o\276\315v\233\343\345\265r7\366\321\230\355z\361\023\005e\002 `\221\250!\372v\366\247H\213m\236\230\377\246\331\236\000\240< \337\346U\230RV\2040\376\035H" >
```

Does the output of the invoke command actually return the proposal response payloads? I've noticed that splitKey present in only one payload, and the order of the fields different in the payloads.

How do I get the proposal response payloads to be consistent?

Comment: what is your chaincode endorsement policy when you install chaincode and what is your endorsement policy when you invoke chaincode?

Comment: @LiXian I'm currently using the default chaincode endorsement policy- I've omitted the --signature policy flag/field in the approveformyorg and commit commands

Comment: In what language is your chaincode written?  In Golang, for example, the order of a map is non-deterministic.
And can you actually post the code for the chaincode function being called?

Comment: @GariSingh It was written in Java. I don't think I can post the code, but logically, this function only assigns values to certain fields- I ensured that its functionality is limited to just this, and there are no conditions involved at all- this is something like an initialization function. (Used Map initially, but removed it when this error came up, so Map couldn't have caused this error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use only one peer to endorsement，like these:

````
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n papercontract --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /home/ubuntu/fabric-samples/extended-test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt  -c '{"function":"plant","Args":["bhut jolokia", "ghost pepper farms", "sustainable agriculture company", "two dozen", "three quintal per year", "yes", "polyculture", "organic, pesticide-free", "direct sowing"]}'```
````

Comment: Thanks! This came up successful- but any idea about why it wan't successful with multiple peers? This smart contract function only sets the values of a few fields, and should be deterministic

Comment: when you invoke chaincode, proposal->collect enough endorsemnt->compare proposal response payload content and so on,when compare fail ,you will get error "ProposalResponsePayloads do not match",you have set five peers in you request,so client will collect five endorsements,and compare them , so this error was(may be) cause by some one proposal response payload was different with others,but I'm not sure more detailed reasons,may be network delay,may be state db are not consistency，so the RW set are different,,may be other reasons